# Does it improve performance casting to lower level types?

Tags: vb.net, casting, performance

Consider this examlpe

```
Interface IInterface
    Property MyProperty
End Interface

Class MyClassy : Implements IInterface
    Public Property MyProperty
End Class

Class MyClassy2 : Inherits MyClassy
End MyClassy
Class MyClassy3 : Inherits MyClassy
End MyClassy    
Class MyClassy4 : Inherits MyClassy
End MyClassy
Class MyClassy5 : Inherits MyClassy
End MyClassy

Private Sub MyHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Here is my question:

    Dim lowLevel = DirectCast(sender, IInterface).MyProperty

    'vs.

    Dim highLevel = DirectCast(sender, MyClassy5).MyProperty  

End Sub
```

The type of `sender` in the above example is of type `MyClassy5`.

Is there any performance differences between the two types of casting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because DirectCast does not use any runtime helpers to do the cast, the performance should be the same. But you should not care about that unless you do millions of casts per second.